# How to add manytomanyfield attributs with form instead select option field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**info**: I have two models customer and items model. customer has ManyToManyField items attribute. my Createview is working fine multiple items save in database while am creating new customer i am able to select multiple items in form. but

**Problem**: I want to add itemform attribute with customer form. I need when i create new customer i want to Save a new item with the new customer...

Model.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    remaining = models.FloatField(default=0)
    
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Items)
```

forms.py

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Installment
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def customer_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        items = ItemForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            if items.is_valid():
                items.save()
            form.save()
            return redirect("/")
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
        items = ItemForm()
        context = {
            'form': form,
            'items': items
        }
        return render(request, 'customer/app.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revise your models by adding a CustomerItem model. This will handle all the records of items and customers that are related.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    remaining = models.FloatField(default=0)
    
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    
class CustomerItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='customers', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

With this implementation, you can save whatever items you want to create while creating also customers.